# how to obtain values from forEach javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've always used `array.forEach(element=>console.log(element)` to see what I am obtaining from array; but now I want to obtain the values themselves.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
array=['1','2','3','4']

array.forEach(x=>x)//undefined
```

What I want to obtain is :

```
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
```

is this the correct approach or there is some other way I am not seeing right now?

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain the values?" Where do you want them to go?

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` discards any values returned its argument function. Perhaps one of the other 30 or so [Array instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods) might be more suitable, all depending what the code needs to achieve.

Comment: sounds like what you really want is `map` method

Comment: I also agree it sounds like `map` may be what you want. It returns a new array of items which are the result of what the callback returns. `array.map(x => x)`

Answer (score 3):

`array.forEach()` presents each value to your callback one at a time.  That's how it works and to use that, you put code into the callback that does something with the values.

As an example:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4];

let product = 1;

array.forEach(x => {
    console.log(x);
    // update the product variable
    product *= x;
});

console.log(product);
```

If you're trying to do `array.forEach(x, ...)` in the console, then you see `undefined` because `array.forEach()` has no return value (and thus `undefined`).

---

Other array functions such a `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.reduce()`, etc... all have return values, and you can pick one of them depending upon what type of operation you're trying to do on the array.

For example, the previous code block, could have been written with `.reduce()`

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4];

let product = array.reduce((total, x) => {
    console.log(x);
    return total * x;
}, 1);

console.log(product);
```

---

And, here's an example of `.map()` that returns a new array with every value squared:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4];

let product = array.map(x => {
    return x ** 2;
}, 1);

console.log(product);
```